# Scripting with variables from file

Tags: avconv, scripts

I have several videos on my PC that I would like to shorten. For instance I have a 30 sec video where I want to have the section from sec 15 to 20 (a 5sec video). To cut this, I use avconv.

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -ss 15 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -t 5 output.mp4
```

This command works pretty well. I have many videos I want to cut the same way. This is why I created a textfile containing the information: input-name, start of cut, length of cut, output-name. Those are written into **in.txt** that looks like this:

```
input.mp4 15 5 output.mp4
input1.mp4 32 10 output1.mp4
input2.mp4 10 7 output2.mp4
...
```

My question is: How do I have to modify the avconv-command to cut my videos automatically? What I tried was this, but it didn't work at all:

```
avconv -i $1 -ss $2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -t $3 $4 < in.txt
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bash, I would suggest something like

```
while read -r infile ss t outfile; do 
  avconv -i "$infile" -ss "$ss" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -t "$t" "$outfile"
done < in.txt
```